# Failure: build failed with an exception a problem occured configuring root project 'android'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building a hybrid app using ionic framework.
I did installed npm,cordova, ionic and android sdk.
also I have set the environment variables.
I was able to run following commands

1. ionic start todo blank
2. cd todo
3. ionic platform add android

but when I run
ionic build android
The build fails.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 29.551 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Hi can you post entire error message ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.Just needed to set the environment variable(ANDROID_HOME & PATH) in the CLI

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and Solved... What you need to do is

- first Solution

  - ionic platform rm android ,
  - ionic platform add android ,

If that does not work then

- Second

  - Remove your all plugins and add again ,

Solved my problem

Comment: Now I m not getting the previous error message.But the command prompt  throws another kind of error.
Found corrupted package.xml at C:\Users\mindshare-11\android-sdks\build-tools\24.0.1\package.xml
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 53.678 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: Did u install ionic 2 in your machine

Comment: No !! i have not installed ionic 2

Comment: Issue resolved..!!! i just set the environment variable(ANDROID_HOME & PATH) in the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the node_modules folder from your project using:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

and then install all dependencies again:

```
npm i
```