# Ionic 3.0.1: build error in android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

Recently I installed `android sdk` from scratch using the [command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

My `$PATH` variable is updated in the `~/.bash_profile`.
`Ionic` and `Cordova` version is updated too. 
I installed the following packages using `sdkmanager`:

- tools
- platforms;android-25
- build tools
- google play services
- google repository
- platform tools

[image: Directory structure]

Upon building the android project, I'm getting the following error:

> Error:
>   /Users/manugupta/Desktop/ionic-3/InvoicePhone/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed
>   with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: /Users/manugupta/Desktop/android_sdk
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650734/failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-a-proble-m-occured-configuring-root-proj) but still getting the same error.

This is the ionic info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

This is the output of `cordova requirements`. Everything except Android target is installed.

> Android target: not installed  Android SDK not found. Make sure that
>   it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the
>   ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

However, I have installed android-25 using `sdkmanager "sources;android-25`.Also, `ANDROID_HOME` is also set.

This is my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/manugupta/Desktop/android_sdk
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/bin/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/25.0.2/:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/sources
```

This is the output of `echo $ANDROID_HOME`:
`/Users/manugupta/Desktop/android_sdk`

This is the output of `cordova requirements`:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: installed 

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 8.3.2
ios-deploy: installed 1.9.1
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

Comment: what is the output for `cordova requirements`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question.

Comment: You should check that.. does `echo $ANDROID_HOME` work?

Comment: yes, it works. I just checked it once again.

Comment: can you paste the output?

Comment: Sure. I updated my question with the output

Comment: try setting it in ~/.profile and relogin

Comment: Did that too. Still having the same issue. I am updating my question with the output of cordova requirements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950169/android-sdk-not-found-make-sure-that-it-is-installed-if-it-is-not-at-the-defau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some missing dependencies using `sdkmanager`.

So, instead I downloaded Android Studio IDE and installed the `android sdk` again (by configuring through Android Studio). This resolved the error.